# Two alternative D3.js scale syntaxes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Say we have a y-scale that converts the data domain to rangebands that are 20px for each data element.

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data)
    .rangeBands([0, 20 * data.length]);
```

I would normally use this scale to determine the y-coordinate of something in this manner:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", y)
```

But in some tutorials, I've seen an alternative syntax.

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d); })
```

I'm not sure what's going on here, and I would like to understand it before I move on with learning D3. I know `y` is a function, so the `d` within parenthesis would be an argument of that function. But we already specified the data input in the y function. I would love to read an explanation of what we're actually doing with `y(d)`. What are the pros and cons of the two alternatives?

Comment: "already specified the data input in the y function" - if you mean the domain() call, that's not the input. You could just as easily say domain([0,10]). y(d) is calling the y function on a specific value within the data.

Comment: Now that you put it into words, it's so simple. But that was just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a minor difference that's maybe left over from copying and pasting other `attr`s that are set with an anonymous function (as in the second case). There should be no reason to wrap `y` in an anonymous function.